# Why am I getting a null pointer exception on getString()?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get data from another activity so that I can make a button visible after a button on that other activity is pressed, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on `getString()`.

```
value=getIntent().getExtras().getString("buttonStatus");
if(value.equals("Visible")){
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    alarmLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

alarmFrequency.java

```
Intent intent=new Intent(alarmFrequency.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("buttonStatus","Visible");
```

So the string `buttonStatus` is supposed to make the button visible, and I don't know why there's an error.

Comment: Show how you are passing data to the activity

Comment: You probably mean to use `getIntent().getStringExtra(...)` as well, but how you populate the intent to start your Activity please.

Answer (score 1):

Please, note that `getIntent().getExtras()` can return null if no extras were set in it and you should check whether you are setting extras for this key `buttonStatus`.

Code to set extras in an `intent`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra("buttonStatus", "active");
```

If you are creating an intent to start an activity and pass data along with 
it

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("buttonStatus", "active");
 startActivity(intent);
```

Code to get extras from an `intent`

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (bundle != null) {
       String status = (String) bundle.get("buttonStatus");  //bundle.get can return null for buttonStatus if not set
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the specific type `getStringExtra(..)` instead.